# Specify name of shared object (shared library)

Tags: go, build, shared-libraries

The names Go compiler generates for shared objects are bad.  Example:

```
go install -buildmode=shared -linkshared github.com/apache/thrift/lib/go/thrift code.google.com/p/go-uuid/uuid
```

Produces shared object named: `libgithub.com-apache-thrift-lib-go-thrift,code.google.com-p-go-uuid-uuid.so` (I need to link together about thirty packages, and this would create a file name several KB large).  Reading through `go help build` and related documentation I don't see anywhere any options for specifying the shared object name.  I tried `-o` but it's not supported.  As an interesting aside, if you call `go install --ldflags "-o foo"`, then Go compiler crashes with an NPE...

Comment: You can't use `go install --ldflags "-o foo"` because the install step won't know what the linker named the file (and that crash has been fixed for a while now, unless you can show a new repro on the current master)

Comment: The output from the Go toolchain seems quite clear `-buildmode=shared and -o not supported together`. Would it be possible to build the shared libs separately? If the naming scheme is a problem for you, I would bring it up on the mailing list or open an issue.

Comment: @JimB possible? - Kind of. Comfortable? - Absolutely not. Wrt crash: well, it's in Go 1.6.1. So, "a while" would be like... five months or so? I understand it that Go developers don't backport anything, even if the bug leads to a total dysfunction? Wrt the explanation: that's kind of lame... seriously, that's not even an actual problem.  Anyways, it's good to know there isn't a way to do it, so I don't have to spend time trying to find one.

Comment: WRT what explanation? I only pointed out that the the go tool is clear that the combination of options is not supported. If you would like to discuss why, or open an issue to change the behavior, StackOverflow is not the place to do that. AFAIK, the primary consumers and proponents of `-buildmode=shared` are linux distros so that dependencies can be packaged individually. I personally haven't seen anyone try this particular use case (combined with your other SO questions), which doesn't seem unreasonable; it's just likely that no one has encountered this issue before.

Comment: @JimB What I'm saying is that wasn't an actual reason. This is just an oversight. No sane person would intentionally do something like that.