# cannot implicitly include runtime/cgo in a shared library

Tags: go, build, shared-libraries

Following my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39577936/5691066), now I'm getting this error when trying to perform all the same steps from this [article](http://blog.ralch.com/tutorial/golang-sharing-libraries/), since I've upgraded from Go 1.6.1 to Go 1.7.1 (I cannot go back to Go 1.6.1 because the linker crashes when tries to compile some shared libraries).

What I did:

1. Installed go in `~/.go/go` (this is later referred to as `GOROOT`).
2. Compiled `libstd.so`:

   ```
   GOROOT=~/.go/go GOPATH=~/tests go install -buildmode=shared -linkshared std
   ```
3. Compiled `calc` library:

   ```
   GOROOT=~/.go/go GOPATH=~/tests go install -a -x -buildmode=shared -linkshared calc
   ```
4. Tried to compile `app`:

   ```
   GOROOT=~/.go/go GOPATH=~/tests go build -a -x -linkshared -o app cashier
   ```

   and received this error:

   ```
   ~/.go/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: cannot implicitly include runtime/cgo in a shared library
   ```

I tried to repeat the steps with `CGO_ENABLED=0` prepended to the environment, but nothing would build this way.  Giving me this error:

```
imports runtime/cgo: C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: gcc_fatalf.c gcc_linux_amd64.c gcc_mmap.c gcc_util.c
```

Is this a known bug?  Is making shared libraries meant to be supported?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've been able to make working DLLs is to use buildmode=c-archive and write C stubs for all the go functions I want to export.  But I was working on Windows for this, I haven't had to mess with this on Linux.  It is a path to investigate.